# Vue-cli Webpack config : how to set correctly the webp-loader

Tags: vue.js, webpack-4, webp, webpack-loader

As per webp-loader [documentation](https://github.com/kavu/webp-loader), 
I am trying to insert the correct multi-loader parameters in my

**vue.config.js**

```
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png)$/i,
        loader: multi( 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext].webp!webp-loader?{quality: 95}', 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]' )
        )
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But it seems to be wrong ...

```
error . = . ReferenceError: multi is not defined
```

what's wrong with the webp-loader doc ??

thanks for feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly from the webp-loader docs:

> Normally you don't want to convert all of your images to WebP format, you just want to make alternate versions. You can use [multi-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/multi-loader) to achieve it:

They tell you that you have to use another loader, multi-loader, to do that.

so the docs imply, but don't directly show, that you actually have to import this loader before, like this:

```
const multi = require('multi-loader')
```

*(and of course you ran `npm install -D multi-loader`) before that)*

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I thought it was a webpack function

Comment: I discover that the image-webpack-loader can load also .webp images . format. I'll give a try